# How to make one larger repository at top of existing repository on GitHub

Tags: github, repository

I have two existing repositories on GitHub, I need to make them public but at the same time I wanted them to be under a common directory so as to ease navigation between projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to keep the two repos, there's a couple of options.

- Create a new git repo and add the existing ones with `git submodule add some_Url path_in_new_repo`. Github lets you navigate to submodules easily. You need to update the 'super' module whenever one of the repos changes, but you retain seperate history.
- perform a subtree merge. This combines the history of the 2 repos into one.

[further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1426163/2290151)